# How do I filter a query when using DAO to upload attachments to Access? "WHERE" is not accepted

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, dao

I need to upload a file and place it in the same row inside Access of the name that´s been typed by the user.

**tried  to use a different query:**

Recordset rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tbl_reg WHERE nome_user = @nome  ", RecordsetTypeEnum.dbOpenDynaset, 0, LockTypeEnum.dbOptimistic);

**Also tried removing the WHERE, and yes it does select the whole table, whenever i place the WHERE, I catch a "Too few parameters. Expected 1."**

```
if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
            {
                try
                {
                    string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName);
                    if (fileExtension.ToLower() == ".doc" || fileExtension.ToLower() == ".docx" || fileExtension.ToLower() == ".pdf")
                    {
                        if (FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength > 1024000)
                        {
                            StatusLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                            StatusLabel.Text = "Status do upload: O arquivo deve ter menos de 1000 kb!";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            string conexaoAccess = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conexaoAccess"].ToString();
                            using (OleDbConnection conexaodb = new OleDbConnection(conexaoAccess))
                            {
                                conexaodb.Open();

                                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE tbl_reg SET titulo_trab = @trab WHERE nome_user = @nome", conexaodb);
                                var parTrab = cmd.CreateParameter();
                                parTrab.ParameterName = "@trab";
                                parTrab.DbType = DbType.String;
                                parTrab.Value = mdl.trab;
                                cmd.Parameters.Add(parTrab);

                                var parNome = cmd.CreateParameter();
                                parNome.ParameterName = "@nome";
                                parNome.DbType = DbType.String;
                                parNome.Value = mdl.nome;
                                cmd.Parameters.Add(parNome);

                                int rowsChanged = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                                //arquivo
                               try
                                {
                                    Random r = new Random();
                                    int n = r.Next();
                                    DBEngine dbe = new DBEngine();
                                    Database db = dbe.OpenDatabase("C:\\Users\\Willian\\Documents\\dbPIM\\dbpim.accdb", false, false, "");
                                    Recordset rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tbl_reg WHERE nome_user = @nome  ", RecordsetTypeEnum.dbOpenDynaset, 0, LockTypeEnum.dbOptimistic);
                                    rs.MoveFirst();
                                    rs.Edit();
                                    Recordset2 rs2 = (Recordset2)rs.Fields["Campo1"].Value;
                                    rs2.AddNew();

                                    Field2 f2 = (Field2)rs2.Fields["campo"];

                                    f2.LoadFromFile("C:\\temp\\test" + n + fileExtension.ToLower());
                                    rs2._30_Update();
                                    rs2.Close();

                                    rs._30_Update();
                                    rs.Close();
                                    }

                                        catch (Exception ex)
                                        {
                                            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                                        }
```

Expected output: The file gets attached to the .mdb if the name typed matches any name in a row.
The first query is executing just fine, but the **openRecordSet** one isn´t, at all.

Comment: Well what are you getting? An error? An empty recordset?

Comment: @user1538301 "Too few parameters. Expected 1."

Comment: Ah. Have you set a breakpoint at this line: `int rowsChanged = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` to inspect the `cmd.Parameters` and ensure it's not empty?

Comment: Yes! But the query at the bottom it´s not a cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(), it´s performed through a DBEngine dbe = new DBEngine();
                                    Database db = dbe.OpenDatabase

Comment: With an Access database you do not use "@trab" in add parameters.  Instead just add parameter in the order of the query.

Comment: @jdweng that part is working just fine, that first query executes and updates the .mdb.
The problem occurs in  Recordset rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tbl_reg WHERE nome_user

Comment: The parameters aren't used until the OpenRecordset is executed.  The access database doesn't not use the name to select the column.  Just the column index.  So it is important that you add the parameter in same order as the Select Statement.

Comment: @jdweng the OpenRecordSet accepts no parameters, that´s the problem, it only reads the table name.

Comment: The parameters need to be numbers @1 where the number are the column index in the database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DAO query locates no parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58733091/dao-query-locates-no-parameters)